# OData EF Core multiple self referencing table

Tags: sql, view, odata, ef-core-2.2

First up, this was working in EF6 however I can't seem to get it working in OData EF Core.  In EF6 I was using VisualStudio's .edmx designer

I have a single Table called FacilityStructure which represents a hierarchy of

```
Facility 
  Building
    Floor
      Zone
        Site
```

ie, a Facility can have 0 or more Buildings, a Building can have 0 or more Floors etc ..

The SQL Table is basically

```
Id PK INT NOT NULL
StructureType INT NOT NULL (0 = Facility, 1 = Building etc)
ParentId INT NULL
Name NVARCHAR(255) NOT NULL
```

The table is self referencing through ParentId and works fine - I also have a SQL View which basically self joins for each StructureType to give the Parent, Grand Parent, Great Grand Parent etc such that a bottom level Site record through this view shows its Zone, Floor, Building and Facility resulting in the following POCO

```
public partial class FacilityStructure
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int StructureType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FSFacilityId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FSBuildingId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FSFloorId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FSZoneId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> FSSiteId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FSFacilityId))]
    public virtual FacilityStructure FSFacility { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FSBuildingId))]
    public virtual FacilityStructure FSBuilding { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FSFloorId))]
    public virtual FacilityStructure FSFloor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FSZoneId))]
    public virtual FacilityStructure FSZone { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(FSSiteId))]
    public virtual FacilityStructure FSSite { get; set; }
}
```

I have attributed the Navigation properties (FSFacility, FSBuilding etc) with their ForeignKey columns.

Since I am using OData EF Core and it has its own ODataModelBuilder which simply

```
builder.EntityType<FacilityStructure>().HasKey(e => e.Id);
```

and the ModelBuilder in OnModelCreating of the DbContext does similar with mapping to the correct View

```
builder.Entity<FacilityStructure>(entity =>
{
    entity.HasKey(e => e.Id);
    entity.ToTable("FacilityStructure", "odata");
});
```

but when I query the OData controller which simply

```
[EnableQuery]
public IQueryable<FacilityStructure> GetFacilityStructures()
{
    return db.FacilityStructures;
}
```

I get the following runtime error ..

```
The query specified in the URI is not valid. 
Unable to determine the relationship represented by navigation 
property 'FacilityStructure.FSFacility' of type 'FacilityStructure'. 
Either manually configure the relationship, or ignore this property 
using the '[NotMapped]' attribute or by using 
'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'."
```

So its complaining about not being able to work out the relationship for FSFacility and I should manually configure it, which I think I am doing via the [ForeignKey()] attribute.  The weird thing is if I comment out 3 of the relationships (FSFloor, FSZone, FSSite) then it works, I get data and I can $expand on FSFacility,FSBuilding which work.  As soon as I add a 3rd relationship then the error returns.

This seems like a bug to me in EF Core since I am explicitly defining the 0:1 relationship and it works if 2 are defined but not for 3 or more.

I realise now that I should have perhaps split the single self referencing table into tables for each StructureType but this decision was actually made years ago and I am now porting the .NET Framework monolithic Webapp to .NET Core and Microservice architecture but require the monolithic Webapp to continue to work 
Any help much appreciated

Comment: I did eventually get this working by adding POCO classes for FSFacility...FSSite and setup to avoid the recursive relationship